# Run mysql_query() with Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

After configuring Doctrine2 and establishing connection I also need to run `mysql_query()` using Doctrine's connection for whole application (I dont' want to use also `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` because it takes time).

How can I get `$link_identifier` (the second argument of `mysql_query()`) from Doctrine's connection?

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

**Version: Doctrine 2.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use mysql_query, that takes away all of the advantages of Doctrine.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html shows all of the methods you can call through Doctrine and still handles plain old SQL. That's probably your best bet.

Comment: I unterstand this, but application is very big and I can't substitute all useges of mysql_query simultaneously. So I want to leave some code using it and some code using Doctrine with only one connection.

Comment: Ok. You might have to use a PECL extension I've heard about - runkit - which allows you to redefine PHP functions at runtime. This would allow you to create a wrapper for mysql_query that would let you run Doctrine instead. The problem you'd have otherwise is that mysql_query requires it's own form of connection, whereas Doctrine requires a PDO-based connection. The 2 aren't compatible to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Doctrine uses PDO. 
The mysql_ function set was introduced in early PHP 4.0 which originates to around July of 2000.

PDO was introduced at PHP5. I think in doctrine you could get the PDO object with this:
 good luck!

Comment: The question is about Doctrine2 not 1.2. So there is no `Doctrine_Manager`, there is `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` which can be returned by `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::getConnection()` method.

Comment: is the same Doctrine2 Uses PDO, I edited my answer to make it Doctrine2 compatible

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine2 uses PDO not mysql_. You cannot convert the PDO conneciton to a mysql_* you have to connect again.